# jquery css values in ems rathen than px?

Tags: jquery, css

can i get an elements css distance values in ems rather than px?

```
    #pointer{
        height:1em;
        border:1px solid black;
        width:1em;
        position:relative;
        top:15em;
    }

top = $('#pointer').css('top');

>> top = 15
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You can't natively, but check this out: http://eriwen.com/javascript/measure-ems-for-layout/

Answer (score 3):

[You can use this jquery plugin :)](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_plugin_for_retaining_scalable_interfaces_with_pixel_to_em_con/)